# How to remove certain elements from an array that start with certain characters?

Tags: python, arrays, string, for-loop

I have a list of expressions, in an array known as `literals`:

`literals = ['-PacketAt(A)', '+CarAt(B)', '-CarAt(A)', '-PacketInCar', '+PacketAt(B)', '+CarAt(A)', 'LoadA', '+PacketAt(A)', '+PacketInCar', 'LoadB', '-PacketAt(B)', 'DriveAB', '-CarAt(B)', 'DriveBA', 'ProduceA', 'DischargeA', 'DischargeB']`

I would like to remove the elements of the array that do not start with a `+` and `-` sign.

I have written the following to try to do that:

```
for literal in literals:
  if not (literal.startswith('-')) and not (literal.startswith('+')):
    literals.remove(literal)
```

However, after I run this for loop, I receive the following output:

```
literals = ['-PacketAt(A)', '+CarAt(B)', '-CarAt(A)', '-PacketInCar', '+PacketAt(B)', '+CarAt(A)', '+PacketAt(A)', '+PacketInCar', '-PacketAt(B)', '-CarAt(B)', 'ProduceA', 'DischargeB']
```

The desired output is:

```
literals = ['-PacketAt(A)', '+CarAt(B)', '-CarAt(A)', ' -PacketInCar', '+PacketAt(B)',
'+CarAt(A)', '+PacketAt(A)', '+PacketInCar', '-PacketAt(B)', 'DriveAB', '-CarAt(B)']
```

From this, `'ProduceA'` and `'DischargeB'` should not be in the list known as `literals`, but they are. Why is this so, and how can I modify my code such that they do not appear? Here is some runnable test code I have provided:

```
literals = ['-PacketAt(A)', '+CarAt(B)', '-CarAt(A)', ' -PacketInCar', '+PacketAt(B)',
'+CarAt(A)', 'LoadA', '+PacketAt(A)', '+PacketInCar', 'LoadB', '-PacketAt(B)', 'DriveAB', '-CarAt(B)', 'DriveBA', 'ProduceA', 'DischargeA', 'DischargeB']

for literal in literals:
    if not (literal.startswith('-')) and not (literal.startswith('+')):
        literals.remove(literal)
        
print(literals)
```

and an online Python IDE to run it in: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that your are trying to remove elements from a list while iterating the list. Try to avoid this.

You can use list comprehension to get the results:

```
 literals = ['-PacketAt(A)', '+CarAt(B)', '-CarAt(A)', ' -PacketInCar', '+PacketAt(B)', '+CarAt(A)', 'LoadA', '+PacketAt(A)', '+PacketInCar', 'LoadB', '-PacketAt(B)', 'DriveAB', '-CarAt(B)', 'DriveBA', 'ProduceA', 'DischargeA', 'DischargeB']
 lst  = [x for x in literals if x[0] in ['-','+']]
 print(lst)
```

Output

```
['-PacketAt(A)', '+CarAt(B)', '-CarAt(A)', '-PacketInCar', '+PacketAt(B)', '+CarAt(A)', '+PacketAt(A)', '+PacketInCar', '-PacketAt(B)', '-CarAt(B)']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I updated my original question with the desired output for further clarity. I want only the strings that have `+` or `-` at the beginning of them.

Answer (score 0):

I will use a list comprehension:

```
literals = ['-PacketAt(A)', '+CarAt(B)', '-CarAt(A)', '-PacketInCar', '+PacketAt(B)', '+CarAt(A)', 'LoadA', '+PacketAt(A)', '+PacketInCar', 'LoadB', '-PacketAt(B)', 'DriveAB', '-CarAt(B)', 'DriveBA', 'ProduceA', 'DischargeA', 'DischargeB']
literals = [x for x in literals if not x.startswith(('-','+'))]
print(literals)
```

Comment: I've updated my post below to show the actual desired output! Unfortunately while trying it with this comprehension, I got the following output: `[' -PacketInCar', 'LoadA', 'LoadB', 'DriveAB', 'DriveBA', 'ProduceA', 'DischargeA', 'DischargeB']`